# Why do I get error message Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[Function: ObjectId]"?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm learning Node.js and I am trying to learn more about express.

I am working on CRUD operations, and I am using Postman to POST a new object into a schema.

My schema:

```
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true,
  },
  quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
});
```

My POST route:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const order = new Order({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    product: req.body.productId,
  });
  order
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

When I POST to the route I get the following error:

```
error: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[Function: ObjectId]
```

- What is wrong with the ObjectId?
- Why is it a function?
- How do I know which ObjectId is wrong?
- How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Just remove the `_id` key on `new Order()`, the `_id` will be generated automatically by MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function because `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` is a function used to declare field type when creating a mongoose model. Since you are passing that to field value, it gives you the error.

```js
const order = new Order({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // <---- this
    ...
```

To fix this, just remove the `_id` when creating new object and mongodb will automatically generate one from you.

```js
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const order = new Order({
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    product: req.body.productId,
  });
  order
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
});
```

You also need to remove `_id` field when declaring the module for it to auto generate

```js
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true,
  },
  quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 },
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving.

Comment: My fault, you also need to remove the `_id` from the model for it to auto generate

Comment: Sorry, did not see that you posted that in your answer. Thanks for helping out.